# Glossaries: Figures

Tags: glossaries

I want to do a glossary of images, like when you convert a wikipedia entry to pdf: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=download&collection_id=d5ba4f760191b80ba2277ebaa560a6f34ed8f2d7&writer=rdf2latex&return_to=Computer+network

How can I do that on LaTeX?

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem? If you don't know where to start, read one of the general introductions to LaTeX so that you know the basics of calling a class and packages etc.

Comment: Maybe a List of Figures is what you are looking for, see, e.g., https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Lists_of_figures_and_tables

Comment: Yes, the answer from Marijin works.

Comment: @Marijn would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was the answer from Marijin. I only needed a list of figures.
Only put `\listoffigures` where you want the list. In the caption, you can use `[]` to set the text that appears in the list of figures:
`\caption[Text to the list]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}`

As defined in: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Lists_of_figures_and_tables